# Межстраничная обратная отправка данных

Tags: asp.net, c#

Почему я не могу использовать объекты страницы CrossPage1.aspx в странице CrossPage2.aspx. Например, на странице CrossPage2.aspx у меня есрь один lable и хочу в этом lable написать текст, касающийся страницы CrossPage1.aspx, не получается, в чем проблем?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CrossPage1.aspx.cs"
Inherits="CrossPage1" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>CrossPage1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
<div>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdSubmit"
PostBackUrl="CrossPage2.aspx" Text="Submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так, на мой ответ не обращайте внимания, я сегодня редкостную хрень пишу.

Answer (score 1):

Это вам не делфи и не винформс, в которых вы делали подобное. Здесь такого нельзя делать! Первая страница НИЧЕГО не знает про вторую! Для того, чтобы передать данные с одной страницы на другую есть масса способов: передавать постом или гетом в запросе, использовать сессию, куки, кеш, файловую систему, БД и тд... Учите мат-часть и начните с жизненного цикла страницы.

Comment: Но разве свойства PreviousPage не для етого??????В книге так написано,но получается использовать нормално

Comment: Можно использовать и данное св-во страницы. Подчистили коменты с кодом, а я уже не помню что там у вас было. Но вообще вот так должно работать: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx

Comment: В вопросе просто про ПревиосПейдж ничего не сказано...